# Does strtoupper work with letters and numbers

Tags: php, string

I have a short line of code that I would like to make uppercase.

```
$box = mysql_real_escape_string(strtoupper($_POST['box']));
```

For some reason, it is not making it uppercase. Could it be because the post is a mixture of letters and numbers? ie; ee588. Thanks

Comment: Try It And See: [Works Fine For Me](http://codepad.viper-7.com/L1gGbK)

Comment: So does `echo $box` show "ee588", or something else?

Comment: @karim please read my question. I quote "For some reason, it is not making it uppercase"

Comment: @juhana It is for inclusion in db, but when I echo it is not u/c. Thanks

Comment: http://codepad.org/NlRHpYCB - seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also try to use `mb_strtoupper($str, 'UTF-8');`. This accept the encoding. Maybe you are having not exactly the letter 'e' like you know.

Link to manual: [`mb_strtoupper()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtoupper.php)

Comment: tried mb_strtoupper and no change. I am using php5.3 is this compatible with that version? thanks

Comment: In my case, I was using Laravel 5.7 and `strtoupper()` was giving me same trouble, after using `mb_strtoupper('abc123', 'UTF-8')` fixes the problem.

Answer (score 3):

this works:

```
echo strtoupper('ee588');
```

you should check that the 'ee' you see is correctly encoded
you can test it [here](http://www.writephponline.com/)

Comment: @bollo - What happens if you remove the numbers? what happens if you print it to the screen?

Answer (score 2):

Check your locale settings. Strtoupper is locale-dependent